# name 'python' is not defined (when type 'python -v' in Mac terminal)

Tags: python

python -v cannot be run:

[image]

I have installed python 3.7:

[image]

I just started to use MacOS system and occurs this problem.
Anyone here can help me identify why is that and how can I fix that?

Comment: The command to check if `python` is installed is `python -V`, NOT lower-case `v`.

Comment: @rrlamichhane: The error message shown is not complaining about the command line argument — it's about not finding the command.

Comment: yep, I just wanna know why “python” is not found

Comment: @CherieLi Did you install `python` using `homebrew` as [documented here](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/).